# How to exclude documents that have reference in other collection?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have a collection named "users" which is like below

```
[{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60360581ce8d63116c5ce6fb"),
    "userType" : [
        "STUDENT"
    ],
    "firstName" : "Shourv ",
    "lastName" : "Das",
},

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6027fdb087d0b94d18611db4"),
    "userType" : [
        "STUDENT"
    ],
    "isVerified" : false,
    "firstName" : "Umor",
    "lastName" : "Ahmed"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6027fd9587d0b94d18611db3"),
    "userType" : [
        "STUDENT"
    ],
    "isVerified" : false,
    "firstName" : "Razel",
    "lastName" : "Khan",
},
...
]
```

Among these users, some are added to a collection named "sectionStudents" which is like below.

```
[{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60d736baee3b6b154ccdcc33"),
    "course" : ObjectId("5ffeec372b2234556439d1da"),
    "section" : ObjectId("6002fae3e58bc750b4394229"),
    "student" : ObjectId("60360581ce8d63116c5ce6fb"),
},

/* 2 createdAt:6/26/2021, 2:36:20 AM*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60d63e44691df002f0e662ed"),
    "course" : ObjectId("5ffeec372b2234556439d1da"),
    "section" : ObjectId("6002fae3e58bc750b4394229"),
    "student" : ObjectId("6027fdb087d0b94d18611db4"),
    
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60d63a9fddcd320314a16470"),
    "course" : ObjectId("5ffeec372b2234556439d1da"),
    "section" : ObjectId("6002fae3e58bc750b4394229"),
    "student" : ObjectId("6027fd9587d0b94d18611db3"),
},
...
]
```

The reference of the "user" in the "sectionsStudents" collection is `student`.

My requirement is now, I want to get all the documents from "users" collection that is not added to a "course" in "sectionStudents" collection.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Is there something in the provided answer that you believe does not address your question? If so then please comment on the answer to clarify what exactly needs to be addressed that has not.

Comment: thanks a lot for your response, I am implementing your approach and let you know.

Comment: @turivishal, I would be very grateful if tell me in addition to the query how to filter out specific students of a specific course for example course id "5ffeec372b2234556439d1da".

Comment: look at this [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Q8m19WocUK_).

Comment: @turivishal, thanks again. but it is not filtering out the students of specific courses I provide. instead, it showing me all the users :(

Comment: can you show in playground, that fails the expectation?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234366/discussion-between-fozle-rabbi-shafi-and-turivishal).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `$lookup` with pipeline, pass `_id` to pipeline, match condition with student field and return the single document using `$limit` because we just need documents for condition only
- `$match` `student` should empty
- `$unset` `student` field we don't need

```
db.users.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "sectionStudents",
      let: { student: "$_id" },
      pipeline: [
        { 
          $match: { 
            $expr: { $eq: ["$$student", "$student"] },
            course: ObjectId("5ffeec372b2234556439d1da")
          } 
        },
        { $limit: 1 }
      ],
      as: "student"
    }
  },
  { $match: { student: [] } },
  { $unset: "student" }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Q8m19WocUK_)